# How to simulate namespaced events or unbind individual events WITHOUT jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-events, event-binding

I have a framework that lazyloads ads when they are scrolled into the viewport. When the page loads, I check to see which are in view and load them. If they are not in view, I create a scroll event and I namespace each one so I can bind and unbind them individually:

```
if (adIsInView("ad1") == false) { 
    $(document).on("scroll.ad1", function() {
        if (adIsInView("ad1") == true) {
            displayAd("ad1");
            $(document).off("scroll.ad1");
        } 
    });
}
```

This way it's easy to set up scroll.ad1, scroll.ad2, etc., binding and unbinding them individually.

This is the *only* part of my code that is dependent on jQuery. I don't want to load a 50 KB file just so I can have namespaced events. How can I do this using addEventListener and removeEventListener? Obviously I can't just use

```
window.removeEventListener("scroll");
```

because this would unbind all of my scroll events, and namespacing ("scroll.ad1") doesn't exist natively.

I haven't found any other posts on this exact topic. I've heard a few people mention that the jQuery source code creates namespacing by storing events in an object, but I'm not exactly sure how that works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind and unbind specific handlers.

```
if (adIsInView("ad1") == false) {
    var ad1_listener = function() {
        if (adIsInView("ad1") == true) {
            displayAd("ad1");
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", ad1_listener);
        } 
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", ad1_listener);
}
```

You can go a step further and do:

```
function register_ad(ad) {
    function listener() {
        if (adIsInView(ad) === true) {
            displayAd(ad);
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", listener);
        } 
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", listener);
}

if (adIsInView("ad1") === false) {
    register_ad("ad1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for PubSub JavaScript implementations with namespaces support.

Quick googling gives this https://jsperf.com/pubsub-js-vs-jquery-events/12 for example.